# about the counting columns meeting conditions using R

Tags: r

How can we count the number of columns to meet some conditions.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4),v1=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.9),
       v2=c(0.1,0.2,0.6,0.1),v3=c(0.1,0.4,0.6,0.1))  


count<-function(x){dplyr::count(x>=0.5)}
df$count<-apply(x = df[,c(2:4)], MARGIN = 1, FUN =count, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This did not work.....

Should be

```
df$count<-c(0,0,3,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums` to count the conditions where `df[-1]>=0.5`:

```
rowSums(df[-1]>=0.5)
#[1] 0 0 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], `>=`, 0.5))
#[1] 0 0 3 1
```